# How to obtain the confusion matrix below?

Tags: r

**Loading the data set in R**

```
data(titanic_train, package = "titanic")

titanicTib <- as_tibble(titanic_train)
imp <- impute(titanicClean, cols = list(Age = imputeMean()))
```

**This is the task**

```
titanicTask <- makeClassifTask(data = 
  imp$data, target = "Survived")
```

**This is the learner**

```
logReg <- makeLearner("classif.logreg", 
predict.type = "prob")

logRegModel <- train(logReg, titanicTask)
```

**Prediction**

```
data(titanic_test, package = "titanic")
   titanicNew <- as_tibble(titanic_test)

titanicNewClean_unseen <- titanicNew %>%
   mutate_at(.vars = c("Sex", "Pclass"), .funs = factor) %>%
   mutate(FamSize = SibSp + Parch) %>%
   select(Pclass, Sex, Age, Fare, FamSize)


titanic_prediction <- predict(logRegModel, 
   newdata = titanicNewClean_unseen)
```

Trying to calculate the confusion matrix for the predictions made to see how well the model perform. I tried the below but can't seem to get the matrix.

```
 calculateConfusionMatrix(titanic_prediction$data$response)
```

Comment: I think `imp` is an undefined variable in your code! Third line of the code gives this error: `Error in isTRUE(lhs) : object 'imp' not found`

Comment: My bad. I impute using the median so it is in fact correct. The code is: imp <- impute(titanicClean, cols = list(Age = imputeMean()))